# Generating a list of appendix table in TOC

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, lists, appendices, thesis

I want to add multiple appendices in this [class](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/thesis-template-for-north-dakota-state-university-ndsu/jssgnvzcctfy), which does not support multiple appendices. Therefore, I used

```
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{1} %APPENDIX_A 
\chapter{2} %APPENDIX_B
 \end{appendices}
```

with `\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}`

It worked well, but I need also to show LIST OF APPENDIX TABLES in TOC and generate them as shown in this images[image].[image]

Here is a MWE.

```
           \documentclass[ms-thesis]{ndsu-thesis}
 \title{The Title Thesis}
 \usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \author{vvv}
 \date{4}
 \begin{document}
        \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \caption{Table captions go at the top of the table}
        \begin{tabular}{rl}
            Number & Month \\
            \hline
            1 & January \\
            2 & February \\
            3 & March
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \begin{appendices}
        \chapter{1} %APPENDIX_A 
        \begin{table}[h]
            \centering
            \caption{Table captions go at the top of the table}
            \begin{tabular}{rl}
                Number & Month \\
                \hline
                1 & January \\
                2 & February \\
                3 & March
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
        \chapter{2} %APPENDIX_B
        \begin{center}
            \begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
                \caption{A sample long table.} \label{tab:long} \\

                \hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} \\ \hline 
                \endfirsthead

                \multicolumn{3}{c}%
                {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
                \hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} \\ \hline 
                \endhead

                \hline \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
                \endfoot

                \hline \hline
                \endlastfoot

                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
                One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
            \end{longtable}
        \end{center}

    \end{appendices}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: I think you should add some tables to your MWE: It's too minimal at the moment :).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I just added tables. Would you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

According to the `ndsu-thesis` manual in the appendices you should use the `appendixtable` environment instead of `table`. Similarly use `appendixfigure` environment instead of `figure`. There does not seem to be any facility for catering for `longtable`. Can you avoid using these or perhaps contact the `ndsu-thesis` maintainer (James Thorne `james.thorne@ndsu.edu`) --- if you do so tell him that I am impressed by what has been done in the class --- ?

Comment: +1: What is impressive regarding the class?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner   My goal is to add multiple appendices by using this class and  LIST OF APPENDIX TABLES in TOC. How could I do it?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner The (automatic) layout of the title page, LoF and LoT automatically included but only if there are figures or tables, the listing of appendix floats. It takes a lot of the design work away from the thesis author. Take a look at the manual.